# Javascript + Node: How to get my interactive CLI function to repeat after user input?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple CLI app that performs some function.

The code is working but it only performs the function once and then stops. I want to do the work, then go back to start to be able to do work again.

The app takes text from the user ctrl+v and cleans it, then saves it to the clipboard. I'm not sure the best way to make it so that it can restart the function until the user closes.

e.g.

```
console.log('Paste text...')
// make `process.stdin` begin emitting "keypress" events
keypress(process.stdin);

// listen for the "keypress" event
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {

  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'v') {
    process.stdin.pause();
    i();
  }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();

function i(){
<more code i have omitted for brevity>
console.log("The HTML was saved to clipboard, paste into the <body> of your Flare file.");
```

Comment: I'm not very sure why you want to achieve this, but a possible solution could to wrap the whole script into a function and then call that function inside `function i()` after printing your logs. FYI - It makes it recursive

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your call to process.stdin.pause, or move the call to process.stdin.resume to right after the call to i(), it will work as you want. Calling pause causes the event queue to empty, and node will then exit once the last function call returns.

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (_, key) {
    if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'v') {
        process.stdin.pause();
        i();
        process.stdin.resume();
    }
    if(key && key.ctrl && key.name === 'c'){
        process.exit(0);    
    }
});
```

This code runs and listens until CTRL+c is pressed.

You can read more about how events and timers work in NodeJS here:
[Node Event Loop Documentation](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)